# Google Sheets - Fixed Colour Selection For Drop Down Input on Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am creating a wedding spreadsheet and on my "Guest List" tab column C contains a drop down list of who the guest in that row in a relation of. I have a "Welcome!" Tab where the bride and groom insert their name and the dropdown list on the "Guest List" tab pulls the names from here.

However, I want to assign a blue colour to all cells in column C of "Guest List" that contain the grooms name (based on the drop down selection) and a red colour to all guests assigned to the brides colour. If I insert the names on the Welcome page and then edit the drop down list and change the colours then it will work, however if the names of bride and groom changed, the colour assignment is then removed.

Is there anyway either in the drop down function or conditional formatting that I can always have the entry on tab "Welcome!" N5 (Groom Name) always have a blue background colour in tab "Guest List" column C: and the entry at "Welcome!" N7 (Bride Name) to always have a red colour background in column C: of tab "Guest List" regardless of what the names on N5 or N7 say.

Essentially I want the drop down list where you pick the relation (column C of "Guest List") to have fixed colour formatting regardless of the names in the fixed bride and groom name locations or is this not possible?

Many thanks

I tried applying conditional formatting but it would not allow me to use this across sheets

Answer (score 1):

You can use INDIRECT to make it work across sheets. For example:

```
=C2=INDIRECT("Welcome!N5")
```

(You'd possibly need to fix C2 to match your initial cell of the column)

Comment: Many thanks, would I need to add the above formula into the conditional formatting or into cell C4 (C4 being the first cell that an entry can be made for the relationship selection)?

Comment: Inside conditional formatting you can choose the option to validate with a formula. Change C2 with C4 if the range starts at that row

Comment: Great! Consider marking the question as answered 